# delay in populating the modal body with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic modal that I'm populating with data by doing an Ajax GET on modal load. The funny thing is that no data is fetched or appended to the modal body unless I do an alert first.

my modal outline is as follows

```
<div class="modal hide fade all-opps-updates">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.all-opps-updates').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // whatever that triggered the modal
        var my_id = button.data('myid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var url = "some url/"+my_id;
        var update_form = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(resp){
               update_form = resp;                  
            }
        });
        alert('i have to alert something!!!!!');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");
        modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);
        modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");
        });
    });
```

What could be causing this? I have tried to use setTimeout function but it still doesn't work. I realized that the GET function is not being invoked unless I do the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is Asynchronous by default.

```
$(function(){
    $('.all-opps-updates').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // whatever that triggered the modal
        var my_id = button.data('myid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var url = "some url/"+my_id;
        var update_form = '';

//----> this will be executed first
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(resp){

//----> this will be executed delayed until the response is returned from server
               update_form = resp;                  
            }
        });

//----> and then this will be executed immediately
        alert('i have to alert something!!!!!');
//----> putting the alert actually introduce the delay and the success callback is executed.
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");

//----> here you are using the *update_form* which will be empty until the success callback is executed.
        modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);
        modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");
        });
    });
```

to solve this, move the code block (which uses response returned from server) into success callback.

```
success: function(resp){

    //----> this will be executed delayed until the response is returned from server
                   update_form = resp;  
                   modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);                
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous. Move the modal body content update part inside success callback.

```
$(function(){
    $('.all-opps-updates').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // whatever that triggered the modal
        var my_id = button.data('myid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var url = "some url/"+my_id;
        var update_form = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(resp){
               update_form = resp;                  
               var modal = $(this);
                modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");
               modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);
               modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");
            });
            }
        });


    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this gives an empty modal. see @Vijay response above

Answer (score 1):

That's because the AJAX call is executed asynchronously. That means that the execution of your JavaScript is not blocked because it's waiting for a response from your server. Your server hasn't responded yet when `modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);` is being executed.

You will need to update the modal's content in the `success` callback function you passed using the `$.ajax` function earlier.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening is that "update_form" contains no data when not using the alert. Hhy? This is because the ajax call is asynchronous. 
here is what is happening:

- code runs
- ajax call is made
- code continues to run after the ajax call

  ```
  modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");
  modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);
  modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");
  ```
- this code is executed after later once the ajax request completes:

  ```
  success: function(resp){
      update_form = resp;                  
  }
  ```

so when the `modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);` code is run "update_form" contains no value;

why does it work when you alert? Because the alert makes the other code wait, and in the meantime the ajax call has completed and set the value of "update_form".
it's not the alert that is making it work, its because the alert gives the ajax call time to finish before the other code executes.

To solve this issue you need to place your code

```
    modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(update_form);
    modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");
```

into the successcallback like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.all-opps-updates').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // whatever that triggered the modal
        var my_id = button.data('myid') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var url = "some url/"+my_id;
        var modal = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(resp){
                modal.find('.modal-title').text("title");
                modal.find('.modal-body').html(resp);
                modal.find('.modal-footer').html("<h5>some content</h5>");             
            }
        });
        alert('i have to alert something!!!!!');
    });
});
```